# A monotonicity proof of a sequence summation

Tags: co.combinatorics, special-functions

I meet a problem:
I have a conjecture that the following sequence summation is monotony increasing in N and tends to 1 as N tends to $\infty$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}C_{2N+1}^{k}\pi^{k}(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}\frac{(1-q)\pi^{k}(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}}{(1-q)\pi^{k}(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}+q(1-\pi)^{k}\pi^{2N+1-k}}$$
where $0<\pi<0.5,0<q<0.5$ and q is a certain prior probability.

This expression is an expectation in my problem under certain background. The fraction term comes from Bayesian formula.

I try some matlab simulation and this conjecture is right but how to prove it via tricky method?

Comment: What is $q$? Is $\pi$ also assumed to be positive? Is it some probability or expectation? If yes, please say this.

Comment: I have modified it, thanks very much!

Comment: In my simulation, I find that it is impossible to show the monotonicity through comparison term by term. From 2N+1 to 2(N+1)+1, the sequence length becomes longer and total summation is increasing, but it does not mean that every term under 2(N+1)+1 is larger than corresponding term under 2N+1.

Comment: So I think the feasible approach needs to treat the sequence summation as a whole.

Comment: @Galor:  Is $C^k_{2N+1}=\binom{2N+1}k$?

Comment: @Galor: Also, are you sure you have the repeated terms $\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}$ in the numerator?

Comment: I find that use of $\pi$ quite unfortunate...

Comment: @Amdeberhan, yes, the combination formula.

Comment: @Ambederhan In fact, the fraction term is the Bayesian formula.

Comment: Can you check "increasing" when $\pi$ is close to $\frac12$ with Mathlab?

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan, yes, when $\pi$ is close to $\frac{1}{2}$, the increasing trend still holds though the increasing rate is relatively slower than smaller $\pi$ at same N.

Comment: @Galor: Your Mathlab simulation is correct, see my answer below.

Comment: @Galor: some comments for convergence added.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan, Very helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Let $0<b:=\frac{q}{1-q}<1$ and $0<x:=\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}<1$. So, your sum now takes the form
$$B(N):=\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\frac{\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}}{1+b\cdot x^{2N+1-2k}}.$$
We show monotonicity: $B(N+1)-B(N) > 0$.

Applying [Pascal's recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) twice, we get $\binom{2N+3}k=\binom{2N+1}k+2\binom{2N+1}{k-1}+\binom{2N+1}{k-2}$. After shifting indices, in the last two summations, we gather that
\begin{align} B(N+1)
&=(1-\pi)^2\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\frac{\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}}{1+b\cdot x^2\cdot x^{2N+1-2k}} \\
&+2\pi(1-\pi)\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\frac{\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}}{1+b\cdot x^{2N+1-2k}} \\
&+\pi^2\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\frac{\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}}{1+b\cdot x^{-2}\cdot x^{2N+1-2k}}.
\end{align}
Letting $y:=x^{2N+1-2k}$, the difference $B(N+1)-B(N)$ equals
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}\left[
\frac{(1-\pi)^2}{1+bx^2y}+\frac{2\pi(1-\pi)-1}{1+by}+\frac{\pi^2}{1+bx^{-2}y}\right] \\
=&\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\frac{\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}}{(1+x)^2}\left[
\frac1{1+bx^2y}-\frac{1+x^2}{1+by}+\frac{x^2}{1+bx^{-2}y}\right] \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\frac{\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}}{(1+x)^2}\left[
\frac{b^2y^2(1+x^2)(1-x^2)^2}{(1+bx^2y)(1+by)(x^2+by)}\right]>0.
\end{align}
We've proven that each quantity inside $[\cdots]$ is term-wise positive, which is stronger than saying the sum $B(N+1)-B(N)>0$.

Since $1+b\cdot x^{2N+1-2k}>1$, it is clear that your sequence
$$B(N)<\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}=(\pi+1-\pi)^{2N+1}=1.$$
So, $B(N)$ is increasing and bounded above; hence by the [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), this sequence has a limit on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. The analysis for $B(N)\rightarrow1$ has already been discussed by Antony Quas. However, in case you wish to see some clues, notice you can estimate the term
$$\frac1{1+b\cdot x^{2N+1-2k}}=\frac{x^{2k}}{x^{2k}+b\cdot x^{2N+1}}\sim
\frac{x^{2k}}{x^{2k}}=1$$
due to the fact that $0<x<1$ and $x^{2N+1}\rightarrow0$, as $N\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore, you estimates $B(N)$ for large $N$ such that
\begin{align} B(N)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}\frac{x^{2k}}{x^{2k}+b\cdot x^{2N+1}} \\
& \sim \sum_{k=0}^{2N+1}\binom{2N+1}k\pi^k(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k} \\
&=(\pi+1-\pi)^{2N+1}=1.
\end{align}

Comment: there is a typo that $1+bx^{2N+1-2k}<1$

Comment: You're right. Corrected.

Comment: There is still a unclear part that: For $k \in \{0,1,\cdots 2N+1\}$, when $k=N$ then the term will become :$$\frac{x^{2N}}{x^{2N}+bx^{2N+1}}=\frac{1}{1+bx}$$ which is unequal to 1 significantly. When $k=2N+1$ then the term will become: $$\frac{x^{4N+2}}{x^{4N+2}+bx^{2N+1}} =\frac{x^{2N+1}}{x^{2N+1}+b}$$

Comment: $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{x^{2N+1}}{x^{2N+1}+b}=0 $$

Comment: You have to teat all summands together.

Comment: Up to now, I can show that given $\pi \in (0,0.5)$, there will be:$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{N}C_{2N+1}^{k}\pi^{k}(1-\pi)^{2N+1-k}=1$$ and the reminder term tends to 0. But it is unclear how to deal with the term $\frac{x^{2k}}{x^{2k}+bx^{2N+1}}$ when k is closed to N. Your clue holds obviously when k is far from N but it can not hold when k is around N.

Comment: OK, I try it via another whole treatment.

Answer (score 2):

So showing this converges to 1 shouldn't be too hard. The fraction is at most 1, and is close to 1 for $k<(1-\epsilon)N$ (for any $\epsilon>0$ and for all large $N$). Since almost all of the mass of the binomial distribution is concentrated around $k\approx (2N+1)\pi$, you can choose an $\epsilon>0$ so that $1-\epsilon>2\pi$. Now for most of the mass, the fraction is close to 1, and so the sum is close to the binomial expansion of $(\pi+(1-\pi))^{2N+1}$.

Comment: There is a typo that: $1-\epsilon>2\pi$

Comment: While k is at most 2N+1, it is impossible that $k \approx (2N+1)\pi$

Comment: If I understood correctly, pi is less than 0.5.  Imagine for example that pi=0.4.  Then I'm saying the mass is concentrated around k=0.8N. If you sum the pmf from 0.75N to 0.85N for example, you get almost 1. Try it in mat lab! And I want to pick an epsilon such that 1-epsilon>0.8.  For example epsilon=0.1 would work.

Comment: Sorry...... I make mistakes on my notation and treat your pi as the 3.1415.......Yes, thanks very much!

Comment: You're a victim of your own notation!